# Regarding comparing MD5 hash

Tags: java, security

I am no security expert and  happen not to give it much thought since most of my app run on local intranet so who
cares about security? :)

But actually, I am trying to make it right.

I have setup JDBC realm on glassfish and I am saving my password now with MD5 hashing using this code from the internet.

```
public static String getMD5(String input) 
{
    try
    {
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
      md.update(input.getBytes());

      byte byteData[] = md.digest();

      //convert the byte to hex format method 1
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++)
      {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100,
                                   16).substring(1));
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Now my question is, during change password use case... is it just comparing if the hash are equal to validate if the password
entered is the same from what is in my DB like this code below?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
String currentPassword = "java";
String inputValue = "java1";

String string1 = getMD5(currentPassword);
String string2 = getMD5(inputValue);

System.out.println("Is equal = " + string1.equals(string2));
}
```

I have read somewhere that MD5 is a one way hashing so I cannot decrypt back the password to string?

Sorry, if my question is too simple but I'd just like to confirm my understanding?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same password will always hash to the same value, so you can do the check you are talking about. Also, in general a hash function cannot be reversed. That is, given a hash of some password, you cannot deduce the password given the hash. However [MD5 has been broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security), so you should use some other hash function instead (like SHA-256). It's also worth noting that to really do this securely, you should salt the passwords before your hash them to prevent rainbow-table attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given the same input string, the hash will compute into the same value. This will enable you to store the hash rather than the plaintext password inside of your database. You're right in mentioning that you can just compare the two hashes to determine if the input string is equal.

You're also right in mentioning that MD5 is a one way hash so you won't be able to transform it back into the original string. However, that doesn't stop attackers from performing a dictionary attack for common passwords. You might want to introduce a salt to your application for additional security. This way, if your database is compromised, the attacker would have to also discover what the salt is and this would defeat trivial dictionary attacks.

```
 return getMd5("myS3cre7V4lu3" + inputValue) == getMd5(valueRetrievedFromDatabase)
```

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)

Comment: The idea that the password file may be compromised but not the salt is laughable. The point of salt is to prevent precomputed attacks. Without an individual random salt, an adversary would need to attack each password individually. Without salt, the passwords can be cracked trivially with a rainbow table (assuming the passwords were of the form computed). With a constant seed, as in this answer, all the passwords using the software can be attacked at once. And after a compromise the software will need to be modified and rebuilt (you want to be sure of doing that in a crisis?).

Comment: I agree that the implementation above needs be changed to store the a random salt along with the password. However, I do think that having yet another input -- another degree of randomness into the input -- does add another barrier of security. Could a database ever be compromised without the web servers or could there ever be SQL injection bugs that expose the contents of the DB? In that particular case, the addition of this additional secret means that an attacker would have to also compromise the web instances to precompited values inside of the database.

Comment: Thanks for the added info David!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I can contribute a bit more. As Tom mentioned, storing a salt alongside the password is more secure, but storing the hash directly into the database has some issues as well :)